# Spark S3 I/O - [S3ServiceException] S3 HEAD request failed

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I want to Save and Read Spark DataFrame from AWS S3. I googled it a lot but found nothing much of use.

The code that I have written is like this:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "**********")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "********************")

import spark.implicits._

spark.read.textFile("s3n://myBucket/testFile").show(false)

List(1,2,3,4).toDF.write.parquet("s3n://myBucket/test/abc.parquet")
```

But when run it I get following error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3Exception: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 HEAD request failed for '/myBucket/testFile' - ResponseCode=403, ResponseMessage=Forbidden
[info]   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.handleServiceException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:245)
[info]   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:119)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[info]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[info]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[info]   at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
[info]   at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
[info]   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.$Proxy15.retrieveMetadata(Unknown Source)
[info]   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.getFileStatus(NativeS3FileSystem.java:414)
[info]   ...
[info]   Cause: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 HEAD request failed for '/myBucket/testFile' - ResponseCode=403, ResponseMessage=Forbidden
[info]   at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.performRequest(RestS3Service.java:477)
[info]   at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.performRestHead(RestS3Service.java:718)
[info]   at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.getObjectImpl(RestS3Service.java:1599)
[info]   at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.getObjectDetailsImpl(RestS3Service.java:1535)
[info]   at org.jets3t.service.S3Service.getObjectDetails(S3Service.java:1987)
[info]   at org.jets3t.service.S3Service.getObjectDetails(S3Service.java:1332)
[info]   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:111)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[info]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[info]   ...
[info]   Cause: org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.HttpException:
[info]   at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.performRequest(RestS3Service.java:475)
[info]   at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.performRestHead(RestS3Service.java:718)
[info]   at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.getObjectImpl(RestS3Service.java:1599)
[info]   at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.getObjectDetailsImpl(RestS3Service.java:1535)
[info]   at org.jets3t.service.S3Service.getObjectDetails(S3Service.java:1987)
[info]   at org.jets3t.service.S3Service.getObjectDetails(S3Service.java:1332)
[info]   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:111)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[info]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[info]   ...
```

I am using

- Spark: 2.1.0
- Scala: 2.11.2
- AWS Java SDK: 1.11.126

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I have tried following things on spark version 2.1.1 and its worked fine for me.

Step 1: Download following jars:
    -- hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar
    -- aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
    Note:
      If you not able to find the following jars, then you can get the jars from hadoop-2.7.3 
Step 2: Place the above jars into $SPARK_HOME/jars/

Step 3: code:
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My App")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
sc.getOrCreate.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key"", "***********")
sc.getOrCreate.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "******************")
val input = sc.textFile("s3a://mybucket/*.txt")
List(1,2,3,4).toDF.write.parquet("s3a://mybucket/abc.parquet")
```

Comment: In the response, the version of `aws-java-sdk` is 1.7.4. Can I use `aws-java-sdk` v1.11.126, as there are a lot of features in newer version of `aws-java-sdk` which are not available in older v1.7.4 ?

Comment: sure you can use but if the old future was not there. then it could be a problem

Comment: Which old future are you talking about ?

Comment: if we have futures using from v1.7.4 and it does not present in v1.11.126, it will be problem

Comment: Other than that nothing will be problem so you can use it

Comment: Oh Ok! So, how can I check if we have futures using from v1.7.4 and it does not present in v1.11.126 ?

Comment: we cant find it, the only way to find is when problem arrives.

Comment: can you tell me , whether your problem resolved or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144819/discussion-between-himanshuiiitian-and-kanagaraj-dhanapal).

Comment: you cannot mix Hadoop 2.7.3 with any other version of the AWS SDK other than that which it was built with. If you attempt to do so, you will see many stack traces.

Answer (score 1):

Set the secrets in the spark conf itself with an option like "spark.hadoop.fs.s3n...", so that spark propagates it around with the work